# Shared mailboxes disabling other users

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010

Weird issue. Users log into their normal windows account. As they move from site to site, they log into Outlook to a Shared Mailbox. If Users 1, 2, 3, 4 decide to login in to the shared mailbox it works fine. When the Shared Mailbox and AD account is disabled (when a site closes) it also disables all the users who have previously connected to it too. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me some details information about your environment?

Did you check the event viewer and find some error messages?

I found an [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/collaboration/shared-mailboxes/shared-mailboxes?view=exchserver-2019) about shared mailbox for your reference.

Comment: Any updates? Has the issue been solved?